# readAsText(file) only reads the last file in a directory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, filereader, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to read all the files in a user's directory and display their content in a text box.

Reading single files works perfectly, however, when I try to read a whole directory, things are getting weird.

While iterating through a directory, only the last file in the directory is read correctly. This behavior is consistent no matter how many files are in the directory.

Here's the code I use for reading the files:

```
results.forEach(function(item) {
  reader = new FileReader();

  // This line is reached
  console.log("filename: " + item.name);

  item.file(function(File) {
    // This one only for the last file in that directory
    reader.readAsText(File);
    console.log("success");
  });

  // This line is reached
  console.log("read: " + item.name);
});
```

Here's the log (from the dev tools):

```
filename: app.js
read: app.js
filename: main.js
read: main.js
filename: SharedPreferences.js
read: SharedPreferences.js
filename: KeyConstants.js
read: KeyConstants.js
success
```

If you have any questions, please ask them, I'm trying this for hours now and I'm slowly getting tired of failing over and over ..

Comment: What is `item` and `item.file` ?

Comment: Note that `File` is a keyword; you may wish to rename that argument...

Comment: sry, its a fileEntry as defined here: results.forEach(function(item) { ... }. item.file is supposed to be a function that returns the file as some sort of blob

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan item.file(function(hurrdurrdurr) { reader.readAsText(hurrdurrdurr); }); didn't work either but thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Specifically, item is a [`FileSystemFileEntry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry)... If you look at the docs for the [`file()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry/file) method, you'll see an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `FileReader` works asynchronously, which means approximately that it starts executing a task (reading the file) while the code continues to be executed. If you want to do something with the result for each file as soon as the load is finished, you need to play with this method:

```
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    // file is loaded
    // do something with evt.target object
};
```

Comment: reader.onloadend = function(evt) { console.log("Successful file read: "); };  item.file(function(hurrdurrdurr) { reader.readAsText(hurrdurrdurr);});

This is what I'm doing now, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Most likely this is because you are overriding the reader within each loop iteration, it is simply not able to complete loading of any file, but the latest one. You need to redesign your code: introduce a counter and create a new reader with a different name within each loop iteration. You must take care to not override the reader until it completes the load.

Answer (score 0):

**My final solution:**

Like abcdn said, the problem was that I was overriding the reader with a new one.

I solved this by using javascript closures (which I had no idea existed because I'm coming from C#).

Here's the full code I used in the end:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: "openDirectory"}, function(dir) {
  readFolderAsArrayBuffer(dir, function() {
    console.log("read folder");
  });
});


function readFolderAsArrayBuffer(dir, callback) {
  if (dir && dir.isDirectory) {
    var reader = dir.createReader();
    var handlefile = function (entries) {
      for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = (function(fileEntry, number) {
          console.log("returning function " + number);
          entries[number].file(function(file) {
            handleread(fileEntry, file);
            console.log("reading" + url);
          });
        })(entries[i], i);
      }
    }

    var handleerror = function() {
      console.log("error");
    };
    reader.readEntries(handlefile, handleerror);
  }
}

var handleread = function(fileEntry, file) {
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log("Read file: " + fileEntry.name + "with the content: " + evt.target.result);
  };
  fileReader.readAsText(file);
}
```

This reads a whole user selected directory and outputs each file's content to the console.